# Parameter name omitted (C)

Tags: c

```
int Number1 = 0;
int Number2 = 0;
UINT __stdcall StaffA(LPVOID);
UINT __stdcall StaffB(LPVOID);
int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    UINT Id;
    HANDLE hd[2];
    srand(GetTickCount());
    hd[0] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, StaffA, NULL, 0, &Id);
    hd[1] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, StaffA, NULL, 0, &Id);
    WaitForMultipleObjects(2, hd, TRUE, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hd[0]);
    CloseHandle(hd[1]);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
UINT __stdcall StaffA(LPVOID)
{
    while(Number1 < 100)
    {
        ...
    }
    return 0;
}

UINT __stdcall StaffB(LPVOID)
{
    while(Number1 < 100)
    {
        ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it said

> ```
> error: parameter name omitted at "UINT __stdcall StaffA(LPVOID)" and 
> "UINT __stdcall StaffB(LPVOID)".
> ```

I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: You have to add a name to the parameters of type `LPVOID`. e.g. `LPVOID variable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your function definition. [`LPVOID` is a data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types#lpvoid), while mentioning the parameter list in function definition, you need to have a paramater of that type, something like

```
UINT __stdcall StaffA(LPVOID p1)  // p1 is the parameter name, 
                                  // which you can use inside the function body
{
    while(Number1 < 100)
    {
        ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Same goes for the other function definition, too.